# $G$-Left Invariant Metric implies Reductiveness

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H \subset G$ a (Lie) subgroup. Denote by $\mathfrak{g}:= T_eG$ the corresponding Lie algebra of $G$ and by $T_eH = \mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ the Lie subalgebra induced by $H$.

A ***metric*** $<-,->$ on $G$ is called ***left invariant*** iff for all $a,b \in G, X,Y \in T_bG$

$$<X,Y>_b= <T_b L_a(X),T_b L_a(Y)> $$

where $L_a:G \to G, b \mapsto ab$ and $T_bL_a$ it's differential at $b$.

Analogously one defines right invariant metrics.

Remark 1: Obviously a metric on $G$ induces a scalar product on $\mathfrak{g}$ by restricting to $<-,->_e$ to neutral point.

Futhermore we call the pair $(G,H)$ (more suggestively the quotient $G/H$) ***reductive*** iff there exist a splitting $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{m}$ with $Ad_H\mathfrak{m} \subset \mathfrak{m}$.

Remark 2: $Ad_h := T(L_h \circ R_{h^{-1}})= TL_h \circ TR_{h^{-1}}$.

I have a question about following implication (sorry, I still looking for the original source; I suppose that it's from from S. Kobayashi's "Fondations on Differential Geometry 1 or 2"):

The STATEMENT is: Assume $G$ has a metric $g=<-,->$ which is ***G-left invariant*** and ***H-bi invariant*** (so $L_a ^* g = g, R_b ^* g=g$ for all $a \in G, b \in H$)

Then the theorem says that then $(G,H)$ is ***reductive*** (so $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{m}$) and the corresponding $\mathfrak{m}$ obtains (suppose by restriction) an $Ad_H$ invariant scalar product.

In the proof one consider $\mathfrak{g}$ with induced scalar product $g_e=<-,->_e$ and sets $\mathfrak{m}:=\mathfrak{h} ^{+}$ the orthogonal complement.

QUESTION: Why do we need the assumption that the metric $g=<-,->$ is $G$-left invariant? Doesn't it suffice that it is H-bi invariant?

In other words where we need the $G$-left invariance?

Indeed, if we set $\mathfrak{m}:=\mathfrak{h} ^{+}$ as the orthogonal complement

then $<-,->$ is for every $h \in H$ $Ad_h$ invariant since it is $H$-biinvariant and $Ad_h= TL_h \circ TR_{h^{-1}}$. Obviously $Ad_h \mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{h}$ since $H$ subgroup and therefore if we take $X \in \mathfrak{m}, Y \in \mathfrak{h}$ then

$$<Ad_h X,Y>= <Ad_h X,Ad_h \circ Ad_{h^{-1}}Y>= <X,Ad_{h^{-1}}Y> =0 $$

since by definition $\mathfrak{m}$ is orthogonal to $\mathfrak{h}$.

Futhermore $\mathfrak{m}$ is obtains by restriction $<-,->_e \vert_{\mathfrak{m}}$ an $Ad_h$ invariant scalar product because $<-,->_e$ (at $\mathfrak{g}$) is $Ad_h$-invaraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $g$ to be left invariant to define the scalar product induced on the Lie algebra of $G$ as you pointed yourself.

Comment: But if $g$ is ***not*** $G$-left invariant then by restricting $g$ to $g_e$ I nevertheless obtain a scalar product on Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$,right? Or do I oversee a detail that makes $G$-leftinvariance neccessary?

Comment: Futhermore in my considerations below in order to settle that $(G/H)$ is reductive and $\mathfrak{m}$ is $Ad_H$ invariant I ***only*** used the $H$-biinvariance of $g$. Honestly I don't see the point why in order to define scalar product on  $\mathfrak{m}$ we need the $G$-left invariance. Naively, when I start with an ***arbitrary*** metric $g$ on $G$ I could just restrict it to $g_e$ and this gives scalar product on the Lie algebra. Where is the error in my reasonings?

Comment: If $g$ is not $G$-left invariant, you can restrict $g$ to $T_eG$, but NOT to the Lie algebra ${\cal G}$ of $G$, an element of ${\cal G}$ is not an element of $T_eG$ it is a vector field defined on $G$ which is invariant by left translation. If $X\in {\cal G}$ for every $g\in G$ one can define $X(g)\in T_gG$. But if $X$ and $Y$ are left invariant and $X(e)=Y(e)$ then $X=Y$. This does not means that $X$ is an element of $T_eG$, since there does not exist a Lie structure on $T_eG$. The Lie structure of ${\cal G}$ is induced by the usual bracket of vector fields.

Comment: sorry for digging up that old question, but I would like to 
clarify your last argument
on 'why requiring that $g$ should be $G$-left invariant is neccessary'.  
You wrote that the reason is that the Lie-algebra ${\cal G}$ of 
$G$ is not only the bare vector space $T_eG$ but the left-invariant 
vector fields on $G$ which set-theoretically can be identified 
with $T_eG$ but the Lie-bracket as additional structure 
is extracted from the left-invariant vector fields and not
$T_eG$.

Comment: More precisely concrete bijection is given as

$$ \psi: T_eG \to \{\text{ left-invariant vector fields on } G $$

$$  X \mapsto T_e L_g(X):= \hat{X} \vert _g   $$

where $L_g: G \to G$ is the left multiplication by $g$. Then 
the Lie-bracket can be defined of $T_eG$ itself by

$$ (X,Y) \mapsto [\psi(X), \psi(Y)] \vert _e  $$

where $[.]$ is the Lie-bracket of left-invariant vector fields
which naturally for a Lie-algebra.

Comment: Ok, but the point is that in all calculations we have done
above we nowhere use the Lie-bracket structure of ${\cal G}$.
So the restriction of the metric $g$ to $g_e= <-,->$ not
sees the Lie-bracket and acts only on bare vectors
in $T_eG$.

And if we do so we would (see my calculations above) if
we still assume that $g$ is only $H$-biinvariant and 
discard the $G$ left-invariance of $g$ obtain a scalar product
on ${\cal G}$ with  

$Ad_h \mathfrak{m} \subset \mathfrak{m}$ and $Ad_H$ invariance.
Or do I missing something? I still not understand where we need the assumption that $g$

Comment: $G$ left-invariant